# Synchronizing screen I/O & pthread & C++

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Is there something built-in about printf() that lets you do well-ordered screen I/O with individual threads vs. using cout/cerr?  I'm scournging around for *something* that will let me do synchronized screen output using cout/cerr and pthreads.  Coming up blank so far; might have to come up with something over the weekend.

Comment: How about a thread that does only output, reading from a pipe. And the other threads 'post' to the pipe, rather than to output?

Answer (score 1):

How would this wrapper work? I'm assuming you want multiple prints from one thread to all show up consecutively... but how does the wrapper know when these "groups" start and stop?

Since you have to some how delineate these "groups" of prints, why not just use a [`pthread_mutex_t`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexLocking)?

```
void thread1(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&print_mutex);
    printf("This ");
    printf("is ");
    printf("thread ");
    printf("one.\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_mutex);
}

void thread2(void) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&print_mutex);
    printf("This ");
    printf("is ");
    printf("thread ");
    printf("two.\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_mutex);
}
```

Comment: I guess that will work, if not a little unwieldy.  That gives me an idea though...  BTW, printf() works fine.  I was wanting to use cout & cerr.  Those break up of course when you use the << operator on output streams.